# Is norm squared of the overall average smaller than the expected value of norm squared of the sample average?

Tags: inequality, expected-value

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N$ be given vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $B$ be a random sample from $\{1, \dots, N\}$. Is norm squared of the overall average smaller than the expected value of norm squared of the sample average?, i.e.,
$$
\|\bar{x}_{N}\|_2^2 \leq \mathbb{E}_B\Big[\|\bar{x}_B\|^2_2\Big ]
$$
where $\bar{x}_{N}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i$ and $\bar{x}_{B}=\frac{1}{|B|}\sum_{i \in B}x_i$.

**My thoughts:**

Intuitively, the larger the sample size is the less uncertainty we have and hence we should get smaller value for the norm of the overall mean. Also, if we assume all of these vector are scalar, would it be possible to prove the special case first?